# How to build extension for iOS8 Apple Contacts app with the Share Contact button

Tags: contacts

I wish to create an app that will show up in the list when I press 'Share Contact' in Apple Contacts app and take one field of the contact and call a web service. Ideally I do not require a UI to show up.

Two questions:

1. Should this be a share extension or action extension. Is action extension allowed in Apple Contacts Share popup?
2. If this is going to be ShareExtension, what NSExtensionActivationRule should be used so that it shows in up in  Contacts only ? Wunderlist for example, shows up here, but not FB, Twitter.

Answer (score 7):

Please add this to your info.plist file.It works like a charm for me

```
 <key>NSExtension</key>
  <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <string>
SUBQUERY (
    extensionItems, $extensionItem,
    SUBQUERY (
        $extensionItem.attachments, $attachment,
        ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.vcard"
    ).@count >= 1
).@count > 0
            </string>
        </dict>
```